# How can I optimize my varchar(max) column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running SQL Server and I have a table of user profiles which contains columns for the user's personal info and a profile picture.

When setting up the project, I was given advice to store the profile image in the database. This seemed OK and worked fine, but now I'm dealing with real data and querying more rows the data is taking a lifetime to return.

To pull just the personal data, the query takes one second. To pull the images I'm looking at upwards of 6 seconds for 5 records.

The column is of type `varchar(max)` and the size of the data varies. Here's an example of the data lengths:

```
28171
4925543
144881
140455
25955
630515
439299
1700483
1089659
1412159
6003
4295935
```

Is there a way to optimize my fetching of this data? My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM userProfile 
ORDER BY id
```

Indexing is out of the question due to the data lengths. Should I be looking at compressing the images before storing?

Comment: If those are pictures - **why** are you using a **string-based** datatype?? Are you base64-encoding the pictures? You should try and see if using the proper **binary** datatype -  `varbinary(max)` - makes any positive difference!

Comment: @marc_s I made an error when creating the DB but the speed issues hadn't croped up til now so I didn't notice. They are `base64` encoded images, but if I try to alter the column to `varbinary(max)` it says `Cannot alter column 'profileImage' to be data type varbinary(max)`

Comment: You'll probably need to add a new column of type `varbinary(max)` and store the images there. I'm just asking because base64 typically **bloats up** the file size quite significantly - so instead of storing 1.7 MB of base64-encoded text, you might end up with significantly less data when stored directly, in binary format

Answer (score 1):

If takes time to return data.  Five seconds seems a little long for a few megabytes, but there is overhead.

I would recommend compressing the data, if retrieval time is so important.  You may be able to retrieve and uncompress the data faster than reading the uncompressed data.

That said, you should not be using `select *` unless you specifically want the image column.  If you are using this in places where it is not necessary, that can improve performance.  If you want to make this save for other users, you can add a view *without the image column* and encourage them to use the view.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is still possible to take one step back.Drop the idea of Storing images in table. Instead save path in DB and image in folder.This is the most efficient .
2. `SELECT * 
   FROM userProfile 
   ORDER BY id`

Do not use `*` and why are you using `order by` ? You can `order by` AT UI code